# Preview a URL in android, the way facebook does before you post a link (Link Preview)

Tags: android, url

I have an EditText to input a web link. I want to preview the inputted URL, similar to the function in Facebook, where we post a link and will see an image of the page, with the title on top and URL at the bottom.

How can I develop this in Android?

Comment: What is it that you've done and didn't work?

Comment: This shouldn't  be closed. Worth a decent question.

Comment: I just tried and implement the Preview a URL feature into my app through [URLEmbeddedView](https://github.com/nguyencse/URLEmbeddedView) and it was working perfectly fine. Before that, I tried to implement almost all solutions but failed because mostly are outdated and do not support the latest Android API levels. Let me know if anyone is facing an issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/) after the user enters a link in the editext to parse out your links OG meta tags (this is what FB looks at)   scrape out the meta tags:

Here is an example of the meta info you want from a recent [nytimes article](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/03/16/world/europe/pope-francis-praises-benedict-urges-cardinals-to-spread-gospel.html?hp)

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.nytimes.com/2013/03/16/world/europe/pope-francis-praises-benedict-urges-cardinals-to-spread-gospel.html"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Vatican Rejects Argentine Accusations Against Pope Francis"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="The Vatican on Friday formally defended Pope Francis’ role in Argentina’s so-called “Dirty War,” amid accusations that he failed to halt abuses of which he had knowledge.">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2013/03/16/world/16vatican/16vatican-superJumbo.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Those who want to implement through a Github library then they can checkout this library https://github.com/nguyencse/URLEmbeddedView