# Sharing image thumbnail and text in title like Instagram Shares to WhatsApp Android

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp, android-sharing

[image]

I need to share the content to whatsapp as Instagram does in picture attached.

The **title** section has an thumbnail of the image and title text and link.
Then **Message** section has a link.

The Message section is straight forward. Any help on implementing the title section will be helpful.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();   
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);   
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "title text");   
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message section");   
sendIntent.setType("text/plain"); 
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

I have gone through whatsapp faq but they haven't mentioned list of the labels processed from the intent.

https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012

Comment: https://github.com/PonnamKarthik/RichLinkPreview

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod Thanks for Ur reply. I don't want to create a view like above picture. What I need is to know how the intent should be structured such that WhatsApp creates a message like tat.

Comment: Have you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21935149/7666442

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod. Sorry couldn't find answer related to this

Comment: It seems whatsapp takes the header information from the link being shared from other application and displays it.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15439110/7666442 && https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778620/provide-an-image-for-whatsapp-link-sharing && https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100917/showing-thumbnail-for-link-in-whatsapp-ogimage-meta-tag-doesnt-work

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod. above mentioned stackoverflow links gives complete answer. thanks. couldn't upvote as i have un voted accidently.

Comment: Welcome @sowmia happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The text you wanted to share");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUri);
    intent.setType("image/jpeg");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    try {
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.MakeText(this,"Whatsapp not found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```